# Shopware advanced pricing - update rule prices via API

Tags: shopware

so I got this issue that I have some rules set up for customer groups (each per different sales channel). I then used those rules in advanced pricing tab for some of my products. Now I would like to change the advanced product price for a single rule using API request. From what I understand, it should be possible using 'product-price' endpoint, PATCH method (`https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/8fe455ace068a-list-with-basic-information-of-product-price-resources`).

I am making a request with payload like below and url `https://shop-domain/api/product-price/fda10622ed67472e82d800618b0c36d1`:

[advanced pricing img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tToet.png)

[amazon rule img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY2KH.png)

[postman request img -204 No Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsFUj.png)

[product-price endpoint img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnAyb.png)

{

```
"data": 
    {
        "type": "product_price",
        "id": "fda10622ed67472e82d800618b0c36d1",
        "attributes": {
            "productId": "675b627cb3034444af9904bb41901a32",
            "ruleId": "ace571bd8e6f48c88f17a551ed1e2654",
            "price": [
                {
                    "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
                    "net": 115.44,
                    "gross": 234.50,
                    "linked": false
                }
            ],
            "quantityStart": 1
        }
    }
```

}

... but I am getting no effect and no actual response (response is empty, 204 - No Content). What am I missing? The ultimate goal here for me is to be able to set up different prices for different sales channels like Amazon or eBay for given products. Also, the request I present here is for single update, though it would be better if this could be a bulk request (I've tried /api/_action/sync upserts as well, but I'm not sure how it should be done - documentation here seems to be quite laconic).

The "id" that I'm using here is product price id that I got using GET method on the same endpoint - for listing all product prices from advanced pricing (last image;  /api/product-price: https://swagger.docs.fos.gg/).
What am I missing here, how it should be done properly? Should I use customer groups for rules or maybe Sales Channels (if it even makes any difference here)?

Comment: [204 means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204)  your update price to success status response code indicates that a request has succeeded.
You can confirm by GET `/product-price/{id}` call.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I made the request you mentioned, price is the same as it was, both in response and in Shopware app. Why does it say the request from original question was successful though?

Comment: no idea why not work

Comment: Found a reason, it finally worked.

It was all about headers.

Content-Type has to be 'application/vnd.api+json'. 
'application/json' won't work.

Bench Vue thanks for trying to help :)